Proof of completeness relation of complex exponetials
In fourier series I came across this completeness relation:
$$ \frac{1}{L} \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi ni(x-x')/L} = \delta(x-x')  $$
So I reduced this problem to proving:
$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi ni(x)/L} = 0 \qquad\text{  for x not equal to 0}  $$
Imaginary part is easy to see because sine will have negative terms as well. But I am unable to prove real part of this equation.
$$ 1 + 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\right) + 2\cos\left(\frac{4\pi x}{L}\right) + 2\cos\left(\frac{6\pi x}{L}\right) + 2\cos\left(\frac{8\pi x}{L}\right) + ... \infty = 0 $$
Please advise.

Take a look at Dirichlet kernel.
